# Convolution of two dimensional gaussian functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

I want to calculate the sum of two probability density functions. I know that it is:

$P_{U+V} (x)= (P_{U} * P_{V})(x)$

If $P_{U}$ and $P_{V}$ are gaussian functions in one dimension, i.e.
$P_{U}(x) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_{U},\sigma_{U}^{2})$ and $P_{V}(x) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_{V},\sigma_{V}^{2})$, then $P_{U+V} (x)= \mathcal{N}(\mu_{U} + \mu_{V},\sigma_{U}^{2}+\sigma_{V}^{2})$.

But what is the result if $P_{U}$ and $P_{V}$ are two dimensional gaussian functions? I don't find anywhere the result of this convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P_U=\mathcal N(M_U,C_U)$ and $P_V=\mathcal N(M_V,C_V)$ then $P_U\ast P_V=\mathcal N(M_U+M_V,C_U+C_V)$.
Here the means $M$ are vectors of size $n\times 1$ and the covariances $C$ are $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

The shortest route might be to use the fact that $P_X=\mathcal N(M,C)$ if and only if, for every $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $E[\exp(\mathrm i\langle x,X\rangle)]=\exp(\mathrm i\langle x,M\rangle-\frac12\langle x,Cx\rangle)$ and the fact that $P_U\ast P_V$ is the distribution of $U+V$ *when $U$ and $V$ are independent*.

**Edit:** Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with PDF $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively then the PDF $f_Z$ of $Z=X+Y$ is given by
$$
f_Z(z)=\int f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Sorry but I'm missing something. Let's suppose that $\sigma_{U}$ and $\sigma_{V}$ are almost zero. In that case, $P_{U}(x_{U}, y_{U})=1$ and $P_{V}(x_{V}, y_{V})=1$. But the sum of both probabilities is $P_{U+V}(x_{U}+x_{V}, y_{U}+y_{V})=1$? Where is my mistake? Besides, could you add any (open) reference, please?

Comment: Not sure the sum of probabilities is relevant here. See the Edit for more information.

Comment: Let me explain myself in physical terms. The variable $x$ represents the position and $y$ represents the charge. Therefore, $P$ is the probability of finding a charge $y$ in the position $x$. $U$ and $V$ are two tests with different probability density functions (pdf) of the charge. The charge is a scalar magnitude that can be summed. And I want to know what is the pdf of the charge suming $U$ and $V$. If the position and magnitude of both charges $(x_{U}, y_{U})$ and $(x_{V}, y_{V})$ is well known ($\sigma \sim 0$), what is the pdf of $U+V$? And if it's not ($\sigma \neq 0$) what is it now?

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are independent then $P_{U+V}=P_U\ast P_V$. This is what my post explains.